# How to create CLContext of NVIDIA CUDA with JavaCL?

Tags: java, opencl, nvidia

I have the JavaCL library and I can also create CLContext with JavaCL.createBestContext(), but it return CLContext, which has only Intel(R) OpenCL platform and it can call CPU Devices, when I need in GPU Device!

Help me!

Answer (score 0):

I found decision, it's looks like this

```
CLContext context = JavaCL.createBestContext(CLPlatform.DeviceFeature.MostImageFormats);
```